# Delete network drive on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-drive

I tried to add a network drive to my computer (FTP to a server I own), but unfortunately, I set it up wrong, and so it won't connect. Every time I so much as single click on the icon in My Computer, Windows Explorer crashes. I've tried using CMD prompt methods but no avail.

Answer (score 5):

Well, never mind, I managed to fix it by creating a network drive shortcut to an anonymous FTP server (ftp://ftp.example.com/) and saved it under the same name and I no longer had the problem and could right click and hit delete.

Comment: Something fishy here....

Comment: @Prasanna it's ok to answer your own question. Although I find it quite unclear what the real problem is.

Comment: I figured it might have been a common problem so I decided to answer when I managed to fix it after posting the question. Not a clue what the problem was, but I assume it was my server rejecting my PC and Windows just going "WELL, I QUIT"